# Wordpress advanced SQL - joins and counts

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, count

**This is how things work**
I use Wordpress category tables and have 2 main categories. The first one is called "`location`" and the other one "`subject`". Both categories have sub categories of their own.

In my example we have "`location`" category 17 and "`subject`" category 3.

**This is what I want to do**
I want to select ONLY the data where BOTH my categories 17 AND 3 are presented.

**This code works so far**

```
SELECT term_id, post_title, post_name, ID, object_id, post_status
FROM wp_posts AS wpost
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
   ON wpost.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id

INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
   ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'

WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (17, 3)
   AND post_status = 'publish'
```

**The problem**
Both categories 17 and 3 exists in the same column. The code above lists the IDs twice if the posts apears in both categories.

Is there a way to count the IDs that are equal in the result? *If ID exists twice, select the post from that ID*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select each post only once, if it exists in both categories:

```
SELECT  post_title, post_name, post_status
FROM    wp_posts AS wpost
WHERE   post_status = 'publish'
        AND EXISTS (
        SELECT   1
        FROM     wp_term_relationships
        INNER JOIN
                 wp_term_taxonomy
        ON       wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
                 AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
                 AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (17, 3)
        WHERE    wp_term_relationships.object_id = wpost.ID
        LIMIT 1, 1
        )
```

Comment: It does not work. If I remove the row with INNER JOIN it at least don't give me errors, but it shows me rows in 17 OR 3. I need it within both 17 AND 3.

Comment: It works like a charm now after you have edited the post. Thanks, saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

This would do it (provided there are no duplicate rows for an entry being in category 3 or 17) without the need for a nested query:

```
SELECT term_id, post_title, post_name, ID, object_id, post_status, COUNT(*) as count
FROM wp_posts AS wpost
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
   ON wpost.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id

INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
   ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'

WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (17, 3)
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   AND count = 2

GROUP BY ID
```

Adding the [count variable and the GROUP BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) will clump duplicates together. You then filter for rows where count equals 2 to get the entries in both categories.

Comment: The idea is great, but does not work. It gives me an empty result.

Comment: Same comment as what I posted to the next post: "AND count=2" doesn't work because count doesn't exist until the rows are returned. I would also recommend putting count into `` because it's a reserved word. What you need is "HAVING `count`=2" or "HAVING count(*)=2".

Answer (score 0):

One step closer? Now the only thing I need to do is a way show the rows that contains "2" in the column "count".

Because the count column is created within the "loop" it didn't work to just write "AND count = 2".

This example displays the result including the count column:

```
SELECT term_id, post_title, post_name, ID, object_id, post_status, COUNT(ID) as count
FROM wp_posts AS wpost
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
   ON wpost.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id

INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
   ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'

WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (17, 3)
   AND post_status = 'publish'

GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: "AND count=2" doesn't work because count doesn't exist until the rows are returned. I would also recommend putting count into `` because it's a reserved word. What you need is "HAVING `count`=2" or "HAVING count(*)=2".

Comment: @Jens: you could just add HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 into your query, but it's better to use EXISTS with LIMIT 1, 1. GROUP BY is worse for performance.